# Asynctask doesn't update progress dialog with publishprogress

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have AsyncTask that downloads Image and it also shows the progress dialog. The asynctask runs very fine and And the progress of the image download also shows the value correctly. I checked it by logging the value of the download in doInBackground() and then used publishProgress(). But this publishProgress won't increase the bar progressdialog.

Below is the code I am using .

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity extends Activity {
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

public static final String TAG = "SingleMenuItemActivity";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int PROGRESS_BAR_TYPE = 0;

//public static ImageDownloadTask imTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String pLink = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LINK);
    String pDate = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DATE);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_label);
    TextView lblDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.publish_label);
    lblTitle.setText(name);
    lblDate.setText(pDate);

// Set Image
    try {
        URL url = new URL(pLink);
        new ImageDownloadTask().execute(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case PROGRESS_BAR_TYPE: // we set this to 0
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading image. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Float, String> {

    public static final String TAG = "ImageDownloadTask";        
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_list_imageview);
     int count;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
         try {

                URL url = params[0];
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    float pValue = (float)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Download so far : "+pValue);
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(pValue);

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.d(TAG,"Bitmap download complete");
        dismissDialog(PROGRESS_BAR_TYPE);

        // Displaying downloaded image into image view
        // Reading image path from sdcard
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        // setting downloaded into image view
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Progress Dialog was Cancelled");
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
        // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
        // example showing ProgessDialog
         showDialog(PROGRESS_BAR_TYPE);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.d(TAG,"values"+values[0]);
//          incrementProgressBy(values[0]);
        //pDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me where I am doing it wrong.

Thank you,

Comment: You should call setProgress() on the dialog itself, and by the way, are you sure that you're calculating the progress properly?

Comment: Yes the pValue is calculated as desired. and shown as follows in the logcat view 

    Download so far : 99.0
    Download so far : 99.0
    Download so far : 100.0

And I have also tried already

    pDialog.setProgress(values[0]);

But still, the progress dialog won't increase. Is there anything I may be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that the progress type of your `AsyncTask` is defined as `Float`, while the `onProgressUpdate()` method takes `Integer` as the type for parameters. By declaring `onProgressUpdate()` this way you're overloading the standard callback method and it won't be called by the `AsyncTask`. Your code will also fail to compile if you add `@Override` annotation to this method. So you should either change the argument type of `onProgressUpdate()` to `Float`, or change the progress type of `AsyncTask` to `Integer`, which is a better solution since `ProgressDialog's` `setProgress()` takes `int` as the argument type.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. I changed the parameter to Integer and added the @Override annotation.